# I have solid projects but the papers have not been published yet. How can I mention this in my SOP?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, statement-of-purpose

I have a few solid projects, however I have not yet been able to write papers on them. I am in my final year of Computer Science & Engineering.

How can I tell them that I have done useful work but have not written papers yet. Since, I want to apply for MS in CS for Fall '19, I want to submit the application ASAP.

I know that I will probably get a paper or two published by the time I am done with my engineering so how can I incorporate this in my SOP?

Any other recommendations on what I should do?

Mainly applying to Canadian Universities and 2 schools in the US.

Graduate program: MS in CS (course-based)

Interest: AI, Image Processing, Computer Vision

Thank you!